# Variables being seen as strings

Tags: python, string

I am trying to convert a program I made in JavaScript into Python so I can use it on a school calculator, but I keep running into issues that make no sense. Often when I run the program it sees the variables as strings, and to fix this I tried to use the `int()` function. It worked up until the area with the calculations. I keep seeing errors when a variable equals zero, such as "invalid literal for int() with base 10" which I also don't know how to fix.

```
intltemp = input("initialtemp")
finaltemp = input("finaltemp")
mass = input("mass")
if int(intltemp) < 0:
    warmicetemp = intltemp
else:
    warmicetemp = 0
if int(finaltemp) > 100:
    steamtemp=finaltemp
    heatwatertemp = 100
else:
    steamtemp = 0
    heatwatertemp = finaltemp

warmice = (mass*warmicetemp*2060)
meltice = (mass*(3.34*(10**5)))
heatwater = (mass*heatwatertemp*4184)
vaporwater = (mass*(2.26*(10**6)))
steam = (mass*steamtemp*2020)
final = warmice+meltice+heatwater+vaporwater+steam
print(final)
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    meltice = (mass*(3.34*(10**5)))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I tried making every variable inside an `int()` function, and it came up with the aforementioned error. I believe it could be related to the `input()` function at the top.

Comment: We would all know what the issue was if you posted the full traceback

Comment: Simply calling `int` does not convert the variable you're passing to it. It returns a converted value that needs to be assigned to something. `intltemp = int(intltemp)` or similar.

Comment: @roganjosh I am not familar with that term, i will update the question when I know it.

Comment: Note, the fundamental issue here still applies to JavaScript.

Comment: Anyway, the variables aren't "being seen as strings", they *are strings* (or more pedantically, they are referring to stings). You have strings, they won't magically become ints

Comment: Note that `int("1.2")` or even `int("1.0")` will throw that error. Maybe try `float()` or the `decimal` package.

Comment: For what it's worth. it would be better to write `3.34E5` and `2.26E6` instead of `3.34*(10**5)` and `2.26*(10**6)`.

Comment: You never converted `mass` in the first place. Everything from `input` is a string, so you would need `mass = float(mass)` (assuming it could be converted

Answer (score 1):

In this line you are doing str * str * int

```
warmice = (mass*warmicetemp*2060)
```

The same can be said for all your other variables.
You need to convert them to int using `int()` otherwise you are multiplying ints by strings.

---

Try this:

```
intltemp = int(input("initialtemp"))
finaltemp = int(input("finaltemp"))
mass = int(input("mass"))
if intltemp < 0:
    warmicetemp = intltemp
else:
    warmicetemp = 0
if finaltemp > 100:
    steamtemp=finaltemp
    heatwatertemp = 100
else:
    steamtemp = 0
    heatwatertemp = finaltemp

warmice = (mass*warmicetemp*2060)
meltice = (mass*(3.34*(10**5)))
heatwater = (mass*heatwatertemp*4184)
vaporwater = (mass*(2.26*(10**6)))
steam = (mass*steamtemp*2020)
final = warmice+meltice+heatwater+vaporwater+steam
print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the input function was reading the input as a string and not an integer.
I made sure the input() function at the beginning was an integer and not a string containing an integer. I acheived this by using the int() function to turn the input as a string into integer.